# Thunderbird cannot send email saying 'unkown user' but sending via gmail succeeds

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

I have set up a new email account on a vps,

I can download by pop3 the emails but if i send email to that account i receive the error 'unknown user' while if i send emails by a gmail account everything works.

any suggestion? is it a client or a server problem?

the vps is a centos web server with other working email accounts
thunderbird is on windows 7

i try sending email other email accounts usually working without problems.

do you need other details?

Comment: You need to give details of what you've "setted" (I presume you mean 'setup'?). What OS, what mail software, what settings are you using? Not enough information at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the server logs may give you the answer you're looking for.

Secondly you can test your email account using raw telnet like this:

```
telnet yourserver.com 25
hello clientname
mail from: sender@example.com
rcpt to: new_email_account@yourserver.com
data
Hello world
.
quit
```